# What is the correct way to manage Kubernetes NFS PV permissions for Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am standing up Harbor using Helm into a on-prem Kubernetes cluster.  I would like to persist data to an NFS share exposed on an EMC storage appliance.  I have created a PV and PVC pointed to the nfs share and test them with busybox to confirm basic setup works.  In the values for the helm chart, I specify the existingClaim and subPath.  However, the postgres database pod fails.  By looking at kubectl logs and describe, I determine the issue is permissions, however I'm unclear how to proceed.  Specifically:

- the init container change-permission-of-directory changes uid:gid of the /harbor/database folder to postgres:postrges.
- the remove-lost-found init container fails because "Permission Denied"
- I manually chmod -R 777 /harbor/database.  remove-lost-found completes
- the database container creates some folders global and pg_xlog, but then fails with permission denied
- I manually chmod -R 777 /harbor/database again.
- the database container fails with "initdb: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty"
- If I delete the folders, it recreates the folders and fails with permission denied.

I assume chmod 777 is not the right thing to do, but I'm confused how this should be configured.   What am I doing wrong here?

Kubernetes file:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: harbor-database-pv  
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi 
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  nfs: 
    path: /nfsserver/somepath/database
    server: platform.mycompany.com
---              
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
   name: harbor-database-pvc
spec:
   accessModes:
     - ReadWriteMany
   storageClassName: ""
   resources:
     requests:
       storage: "1Gi"
   volumeName: "harbor-database-pv"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: harbor-postgres
spec:
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: harbor-postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: harbor-postgres
    spec:    
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:13
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: pgbench
        - name: PGUSER
          value: pgbench
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: postgres@123
        - name: PGBENCH_PASSWORD
          value: superpostgres
        - name: PGDATA
          value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgredb
      volumes:
      - name: postgredb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: harbor-database-pvc
```

First init logs from kubectl logs :

```
fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
initdb: error: could not create directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_wal/archive_status": Permission denied
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
initdb: warning: could not open directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/global": Permission denied
initdb: warning: could not open directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_wal": Permission denied
initdb: error: failed to remove contents of data directory
creating subdirectories ...
```

Subsequent init logs:

```
initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg" exists but is not empty
If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg" or run initdb
with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg".
```

Comment: I would not persist PostgreSQL data on NFS.

Comment: Ok- what would be the preferred way to persist data volume for Postgres running inside Kubernetes?

Comment: Plain Persistent Volumes, but your would want replication e.g. using Crunchy operator: https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator

Comment: Does @Jonas suggestion solves it for you? As he mentioned NFS is not recommended for PostgreSQL.

Comment: It is informative, but I still feel what I'm doing should be possible.  Postgres docs say NFS is ok: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html (see last section, 18.2.2.1. NFS)  Using local storage means we must rely on physical disk on one host.  Standing up an operator is more overhead than I'm looking for right now, and would still need some storage.  I don't need HA- I'd just like a simple instance where the data is on our storage array.

Comment: Could you share logs from postgresql pods?

Answer (score 0):

Overall bad idea to persist databased on nfs/efs . Plain PV will do the job but dont try replication.

Comment: If using local-storage pv, won't I lose data if the container migrates to another host or is restarted?

Comment: No dont worry .Thats the reason the pv are for.